# Assembly reference or Namespace of Worker class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) tutorial to understand Dependency Injection on .NET.
I am missing an assembly reference or `using` directive for the class `Worker` in the following code:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using DiExample;  // MessageWriter class and interface like in the Dependency Injection tutorial

var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
builder.ConfigureServices(
    services => services.AddHostedService<Worker>().AddScoped<IMessageWriter, MessageWriter>()
);
```

(The compiler error is `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Worker' could not be found (are you m  issing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\dwood\Desktop\dotnet-di-example\dotnet-di-example.csproj]` )

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=netcore-cli) guide, the assembly in question should be in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` package. However, the references in my `csproj` file are:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I am using the dotnet CLI, dotnet version 6.0.400 (the most recent version) on Windows.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where is `Worker` defined? Is your class or from some external package?

Comment: Ahhh, my mistake. I totally missed the custom implementation of `Worker`. Sorry & thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: It was not a missing assembly reference but simply my bad by missing out on the custom `Worker` class implementation while following the tutorial.